# Custom pagination code is not working

Tags: pagination

I am using the below code for pagination. However, it is not working. It's showing all of the pages numbers nicely, but when I click on a page number the first page is always displayed.

```
global $wp_query;  
$total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;  
if ( $total_pages > 1 ) {  
    $current_page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );  
    echo paginate_links( array(  
        'base' => get_pagenum_link( 1 ) . '%_%',  
        'format' => '/page/%#%',  
        'current' => $current_page,  
        'total' => $total_pages,  
    ) );  
}
```

My permalink settings are set to:

> localhost/my-blog/sample-post/

And query post:

> $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 2);

If i change the format to

> '/page=%#%'

its providing me 404 error.

anybody please give me idea what to do next for working this pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
check below code for pagination.

global $paged;
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;

$wp_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page' => 2, 'paged' => $paged ) ); 
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
// Your post content.
endwhile;
echo paginate_links( $args );
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text'    => __('Previous'),
'next_text'    => __('Next')
) );
/* Code Ends

Check this code and let me know.
```

Comment: use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to modify the main query rather than creating a new query in the template.